# If input field is empty, disable submit button

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to disable submit button if the user hasn't provided any text.

At first sight it looks that everything works just fine, but if user types some text, then deletes it, the submit button becomes enabled.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val.length !=0){
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Add an else statement that disables it

Comment: You never disable it if the length is 0.

Comment: What about attacks? using enable and disable attributes are not secure....Just click f12 in your browser, find the submit button in the html, and then remove the disabled ! It will submit the form even if the inputs are empty.

Comment: @Elnaz indeed, so you still need to include the appropriate checks in your backend. Still, this is useful as a UI improvement. On another note, `keyup` would not be my first choice. What if a user cuts the text? `.on('input', ...` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You are disabling only on `document.ready` and this happens only once when `DOM` is ready but you need to `disable` in keyup event too when textbox gets empty. Also change `$(this).val.length` to `$(this).val().length`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

Or you can use conditional operator instead of if statement. also use **prop instead of attr** as attribute is not [recommended by jQuery 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and above for disabled, checked etc.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
});
```

Comment: How to do that with multiple id elements? for example #name, #email, #message

Comment: If you use values for the inputs, the last won't work.

Answer (score 11):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);

    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    })
});
```

Check [demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nh8Xw/)

You are missing the else part of the if statement (to disable the button again if textbox is empty) and parentheses `()` after `val` function in  `if($(this).val.length !=0){`

Comment: Note: if you use arrow function for keyup, it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jquery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">       
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <input type="text" id="message" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  

      var checkField;

      //checking the length of the value of message and assigning to a variable(checkField) on load
      checkField = $("input#message").val().length;  

      var enableDisableButton = function(){         
        if(checkField > 0){
          $('#sendButton').removeAttr("disabled");
        } 
        else {
          $('#sendButton').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
      }        

      //calling enableDisableButton() function on load
      enableDisableButton();            

      $('input#message').keyup(function(){ 
        //checking the length of the value of message and assigning to the variable(checkField) on keyup
        checkField = $("input#message").val().length;
        //calling enableDisableButton() function on keyup
        enableDisableButton();
      });
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do:

```
function toggleButton(ref,bttnID){
    document.getElementById(bttnID).disabled= ((ref.value !== ref.defaultValue) ? false : true);
}


<input ... onkeyup="toggleButton(this,'bttnsubmit');">
<input ... disabled='disabled' id='bttnsubmit' ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that use *coffeescript*, I've put the code we use globally to disable the submit buttons on our most widely used form. An adaption of Adil's answer above.

```
$('#new_post button').prop 'disabled', true
$('#new_post #post_message').keyup ->
    $('#new_post button').prop 'disabled', if @value == '' then true else false
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sendValueButton').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('.sendValueButton').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('.sendValueButton').attr('disabled',true);
    })
     $('#message1').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('.sendValueButton').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('.sendValueButton').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

```css
.btn{
    color:red;
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="message1">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="message">
    <button class="btn sendValueButton" type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't just a code-only answer. Describe the problem that you have solved.

Comment: The code is the solution for the bug!
This code will disable the button if the field still empty, so you can use  it to disable the button and able it when all the fields filled.