# If input field is empty, disable submit button v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

In my websites I tried these 2 codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#message').keyup(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length != 0)
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled', false);            
        else
            $('.sendButton').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

Then I tried this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
});
```

How can I edit either of those so that my button isn't disabled when the only thing you do is right click paste in the textarea (`#message`)? With those codes it only works if you initially click it. I want the button to be disabled if there is no text in textarea, but at the same time I want it be enabled if it has text but there hasn't been an initial left click. Ie. the only thing you do when the page loads is right click, paste, then click button (and it should work).

Thanks in advance!

PS: both codes come from this topic: [If input field is empty, disable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699094/if-input-field-is-empty-disable-submit-button)

Comment: Try binding to the `onChange` event instead of keyup.

Comment: Here's the rest of the code ? `textarea (#message)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use .change() event handler. It will be dispatched when input value will be changed. So when somebody just pastes on the field it will be changed so you'll get your action.

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot interpret your answer since i'm a newbie with code. would you mind helping me out? this is the code I wrote in this forum, but modified for my page: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#link').keyup(function(){
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
});  
</script>

Comment: Here, I've provided you with codepen, but changed it a bit (not using .change()) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVBMWP  please be advised it does not work with IE <9.
*here is js code* `$('input.writeme').on('input',function(e){
 $('.readme').text($('.writeme').val())
});`

*and here is html*
`<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="text" class="writeme" placeholder="write here"/>
<div class="readme">Here you'll see changes</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#message').on('input',function(){    

        $('.sendButton').prop('disabled', this.value === "");     
        })
}); 

});
```

Extending to the above code, if any browser having paste issues use **input propertychange paste** rather **input**