# how to disable the button based on result of javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the button based on the javascript result of textboxes if there is incorrect email id then the button should be disabled .Help me over this.If there is incorrect email and phone no ,I Want to disable my Button function or button.My problem is I'm using separate javascript functions for textboxes so how can disable the button based on other javascript function.Help me over this

```
<div align="right">
</div>
<div id="div">
<center> <h3>REGISTER</h3></center>
<div id="output" align="center">
</div>
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Firstname</label>
<td>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" required=""> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Lastname</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"  required="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Email</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="">
</td>
<td id="error" style="display:none;color:red">
invalidemail
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Password</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Confirm password</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" required="">
</td>
<span id="pass"></span>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Phone no</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="phoneno" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" id="phoneno" required="" maxlength="10">
</td>
<td id="invalidphone" style="display:none;color:red">
invalidphoneno
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<a href="login.php">Login?</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#email').on('keypress', function() {
    var re = /([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value);
    if(!re) {
        $('#error').show();
    } else {
        $('#error').hide();
    }
});
$('#phoneno').on('keypress',function(){
  var phone=/^\+{0,2}([\-\. ])?(\(?\d{0,3}\))?([\-\. ])?\(?\d{0,3}\)?([\-\. ])?\d{3}([\-\. ])?\d{4}/.test(this.value);
  if(!phone){
    $('#invalidphone').show();
  }
  else
  {

    $('#invalidphone').hide();
  }
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
var first=$('#firstname').val();
var last=$('#lastname').val();
var Email=$('#email').val();
var pass=$('#password').val();
var confirm=$('#confirmpassword').val();
var phone=$('#phoneno').val();


$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"register.php",
     data:{

       firstname:first,
        lastname:last,
        email:Email,
        password:pass,
        confirmpassword:confirm,
        phoneno:phone,

       },
      success:function(data){
        if($.trim(data)==='successfully registered')
        {
        $('#output').html(data);
        }
        else
        {
        $('#pass').html(data);
        }
      },
      error:function()
      {
        alert("error");
      }

});
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Have submit button disabled initially till you have all form
   elements as proper
2. With the HTML5 input (email and text) fields, you already have the required attribute present, but need to put required="required"
3. Have an onChange event for the last (required) field, check if the
   validation is successful.

Check this for more details and additional info 
[If input field is empty, disable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699094/if-input-field-is-empty-disable-submit-button)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#submit").attr("disabled", true);` to disable and `$("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");` to enable the button

```
$('#phoneno').on('keypress',function(){
  var phone=/^\+{0,2}([\-\. ])?(\(?\d{0,3}\))?([\-\. ])?\(?\d{0,3}\)?([\-\. ])?\d{3}([\-\. ])?\d{4}/.test(this.value);
  if(!phone){
    $("#submit").attr("disabled", true);  // disable submit btn
    $('#invalidphone').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");  //enable submit btn
    $('#invalidphone').hide();
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply disable the button at the top of your javascript.

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
```

Then in your regex, if it's true, set it to false.

EDIT - It's probably best to set your regex variables global and then you can do if statement for both regex.

```
if (re && phone) {
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
}
```