# Enable submit button based on @Html.Textboxfor and @Html.DropDownList filled

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, required

Currectly I am creating a page which has many @Html.TextBoxFor and @Html.DropDownList. Based on the value entered in it the submit button should be enabled. I tried required but it doesn't work for me. Only if the values are entered in the fields the submit button should be enabled. Any help please?

Html code snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Period:<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            @Html.DropDownList("Quarter", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q1", Value = "1" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q2", Value = "2" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q3", Value = "3" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q4", Value = "4" }) }, "-- Select Quarter --", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Quarter", @required = "required" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">ID:<span class="Imp">*</span> </label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.detailsConfig.ID, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ID", @required = "required" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
```

Comment: Try using `Javascript`

Comment: Welcome to the community . Please post what you have tried

Comment: are u binding this with form submit button should be inside the form

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth Hi, I tried just the required keyword as i mentioned in the code above.

Comment: @required wont work. You need to enable and disable the buttons using jQuery . Find the length of the text box values and then enable and disable using by setting disabled property of the submit button.

Comment: Why are you wanting this. Your model properties should have validation attributes, and include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor(...)` in your view for each property and enable client side validation (the form will not be submitted and the error messages will be displayed if its invalid)

Comment: put <form> at the top and close it after the submit button</form>

Comment: @BinoyKumar I am using "Html.BeginForm" Is this ok?

Comment: @Global - That should do.  Try this one. Requesting you to search in stackoverflow before posting the question inorder to avoid downvoting

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699094/if-input-field-is-empty-disable-submit-button

Comment: @Global ya it is fine