# How to disable a button at an empty text/number field

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to disable a button in HTML on the condition that required fields are empty. The code given below is of the form in which the button is there:

```html
<form>
  Name*: <input type="text" size="20" name="name" /> <br /><br /> Surname: <input type="text" size="20" name="sur_name" /> <br />
  <br /><br /> Mobile number: <input type="tel" size="15" name="mob" /> <br /><br /> E-mail id*: <input type="Email" size="30" name="user_id" /> <br /><br /> Password*: <input type="Password" size="30" name="pw1" /> <br /><br /> Confirm Password*: <input
    type="password" size="30" name="pw2" /> <br /><br /><br /><br /> I accept the terms and conditions <input type="checkbox" name="t&c" /><br /><br />

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Sign up now" onclick=window.location.href="https://www.google.co.in/signup" />
</form>
```

The form is actually a dummy sign up screen, yet the screen redirected is a 404 error screen, but I want the button to be disabled if certain fields are empty, and that it reloads the page if the two values for password are different.

I don't know JS completely, so please edit the code so that the parameters are clear.

Comment: The starred ones are the required fields

Comment: You can find a lot of relevant answers here. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17699094/863110). P.S. They use jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<input type="text" size="20" name="name" />` with `<input type="text" size="20" name="name" required/>`

Replace `<input type="Email" size="30" name="user_id" />` with `<input type="Email" size="30" name="user_id" required/>`

Replace `<input type="Password" size="30" name="pw1" />` with `<input type="Password" size="30" name="pw1" required/>`

Replace `<input type="password" size="30" name="pw2" />` with `<input type="password" size="30" name="pw2" required/>`

Comment: Could you please send the entire php code? I don't really know how to do

Comment: I tried to add JavaScript, the button was not disabling as per the script and when I disabled it manually, through the code, It didn't re-enable