# How to disable a form button unless user starts typing something in a text field in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails which:

- shows a blank text field if debit value is 0
- it shows the debit value in the text field if the debit value is non-zero

```rb
<%= form_for(@debit, remote: true, html: { id: 'match_form' }) do |f| %>
        <% if @debit.match_id == 0 %>
          <%= f.text_field :match_id, value: '',  style: "width:82px" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.text_field :match_id, style: "width:82px" %>
        <% end %>
        <br/><br/>
   <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary', style: "width:38px;padding:0px" %>
   <%= button_tag 'Cancel', class: 'btn btn-secondary', id: 'match_cancel', style: "width:52px;padding:0px" %>
<% end%>
```

There's a submit and cancel button shown below the text field (as shown in the code above).

When debit value is 0, the text field is blank. Now, when the text field is blank, I would like the submit button to be disabled. I would like the same to ne enabled as soon as the user starts typing some value.

How can I achieve this? Please help!

Comment: This question is incorrectly tagged, because disabling the button must be done with JavaScript, not with Rails itself. This similar question may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699094/if-input-field-is-empty-disable-submit-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If input field is empty, disable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699094/if-input-field-is-empty-disable-submit-button)

Comment: Thanks much for the inputs. Quick question? What would be the id of the submit button in my code above? (How do I refer to the submit button in my JavaScript code? What id do I use to refer to the submit button?)